# Can anybody explain what is 'a soft sentence' ? why they use words like that?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Can anybody explain what is 'a soft sentence'? Why do they use words like that?

**Context**

"they" are the German government, Hitler committed an offence and they gave him a 'soft sentence' the whole sentence is 'Sympathetic judges gave Hitler a soft sentence for treason. He was imprisoned in the nearby town of Landsberg.'

Comment: Who is `they`, what are `they` and why are `they` soft?

Comment: they are the German government, Hitler offenced them, so they gave him a 'soft sentence' the whole sentences is 'Sympathetic judges gave Hitler a soft sentence for treason
He was imprisoned in the nearby town of Landsberg.' Help me !

Comment: Welcome The Nobody - When you ask questions, please don't make us guess what you are talking about. At first I assumed that you meant a sentence as in English Grammar.  I'll edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are using this in the context of a legal ruling. A soft sentence is a sentence (i.e. a punishment by a judge) that is soft (i.e. not as hard hitting).

> Jimmy was handed a soft sentence of 15 years for stabbing his dog

This means that Jimmy stabbed his dog and only got 15 years in prison, with the time frame of 15 years being 'soft'

> Jimmy was handed a hard sentence of 45 years for stabbing his dog

This means that Jimmy stabbed his dog and got a massive 45 years in prison, with the time frame of 15 years being 'hard'.

So, to answer your question, 'soft' is being used metaphorically here.